# Asp MVC Entity Framework Polymorphic Abstract Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a polymorphic relationship in C# similar to what laravel offers where you can have a table such as Uploads and
it has two properties called uploadable_id and uploadable_type

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| id | uploadable_id |   uploadable_type |            file_path               |
+----+---------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 |    2          |      Post         |        uploads/xyz                 |
|  2 |    6          |    comment        |        uploads/abc                 |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

If we want to add another model that has many uploads in the future we just need to add that in uploadable_type 
without adding more field like something_id into upload table.

I've attempted to do something similar in C# by using an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class AttachableEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Upload> Files { get; set; }
}


public class Post :  AttachableEntity
{
   // other properties
}

public class Comment :  AttachableEntity
{

   public int PostId { get; set; }

   public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

   // other properties
}

 public class Upload 
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Filename { get; set; }

        public int AttachableEntityId { get; set; }

        public AttachableEntity AttachableEntity { get; set; }
 }


  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Upload> Upload { get; set; }
  }
```

But when I add a migration and update the database it generate a table called AttachableEntity which include properties from
all models that inherit this abstract class?

If AttachableEntity is abstract why is a table called AttachableEntity being generated and no Post or Comment table are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always forget how the conventions in EF work but what you are seeing is a TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) strategy. You seem to want TPT (Table Per Type).

You can control this with attributes in the model but better to use the fluent API in the DbContext:

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().ToTable("Posts");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().ToTable("Comments");
    }
  }
```

I spotted a [tutorial here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the tip. One question though, if I have e.g a post id, I can get all related uploads as follows: `var post = context.Post.Include(x => x.Upload).Where(x => x.Id = id).ToList();` But how do I identify the related model from the Upload class i.e. if all I have is the Upload file id? In the AttachableEntity table there is no discriminator field?

Comment: You should probably move the Id to the base class. And you should only have a `DbSet<Attachable>` and then you can filter on type with `Attachables.OfType<Post>().Where(...)`